# Google Analytics 'internal error please try again' on trying to save report

Tags: google-analytics, customization

I am trying to save report in Google Analytics, but I receive 'internal error, Please try again' please see screenshot

[image]

I have other similar apps however no issue there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question but rather a question about saving a report in Google Analytics.